# Symfony 3 - I can't use lower in DQL function

Tags: php, symfony, request, dql

I've a function and i would like put my attributes to lower :

```
public function getHomonymes($nom, $prenom)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder("u")
    ->select("count(u.id")
    ->where("lower(u.nom) = :nom")
    ->andWhere("lower(u.prenom) = :prenom")
    ->setParameter("nom",strtolower($nom))
    ->setParameter("prenom",strtolower($prenom));
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 52: Error: Expected
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got 'u'

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't have table from condition in your query => select FROM where. Your createQueryBuilder() seems to doesn't know the name of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a closing parenthesis in your select statement

```
->select("count(u.id")
```

should be

```
->select("count(u.id)")
```